# Python, Django, Storing a class name to later instantiate an object?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to store `my_app.path.to.my_class` in a database

I'm going use this to instantiate the appropriate class object using `from django.utils.module_loading import import_string`

I'm worried this scheme doesn't handle well the situation where I need to change the module name, or path. would there be a better scheme to handle this?

second, in order to store the class name for a class object, I think there's a way to get the fully qualified name for the class somehow.
i.e. Is there a way for me to generate the `fully_qualified_class_name` below?

```
class FooShipping(object):
  fully_qualified_class_name = 'store.shipping.foo_shipping.FooShipping'
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything without more context, you are only describing your suggested solution and not the problem it addresses.

Comment: You have only described more of your solution, what I'm asking for is an explanation as to _why_ you need this rather unusual feature. My experience is that when you end up in this situation you've usually taken a wrong turn earlier in the design.

Comment: I think that your approach is ok. If you'll change module name, well, you'll need to change your other code. It's called refactoring :) Anyway, if you'll use classic approach with module importing with `import`, you'll need to change your code too in case of modules renaming, it's normal situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary to do this:

```
MyClass = globals()[fully_qualified_class_name]
```

then initialize an object using that class:

```
my_object = MyClass()
```